# why phpmailer function doesn't work

Tags: php

I use phpmailer to send emails.but encounter some troubles.

```js
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.qq.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '100****@qq.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'w******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('10****6@qq.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('1***65@qq.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('1*****56@qq.com', 'Information');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

it shows Message could not be sent.

> Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl

and i change php.ini `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` and it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart Apache in order for the php.ini change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If enable extension does not work, please install dll or read more about [openssl here](http://php.net/manual/es/openssl.installation.php).